# Faster way to search list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, binary-search, linear-search

I'm trying to make my program run more efficiently, and I believe fixing this linear search would do a great deal of help in terms of speed, but am curious as to how I'd go about changing this to something like binary search, as I believe the list isn't necessarily ordered. Is there some way of ordering the list based on it's first argument `key`?

What I'm working with currently:

```
int* key_sequences::data(int key){
    for(it=myList.begin(); it!=myList.end(); ++it){
        if(it->first==key){
            return &(it->second[0]);
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
};
```

Comment: Binary search is not possible without a sorted sequence.

Comment: The obvious answer would be to quit using a list, and replace it with a more suitable data structure (possibly a `map` or `unordered_map`, from the looks of things). Depending on when/how often insertion/deletion happens, you might also consider a "FlatMap"--binary searching in a sorted array.

Comment: Often a sequence is searched repeatedly, for successive keys. Caching the last search result can then reduce the total time from O(n²) to O(n). But I'd change the data structure to something more suitable, like a `map`.

Comment: have you considered using `std::map` ?

Comment: The only way to find something in an unordered list is to traverse the entire list.  If the list was ordered or sorted, you could use a better algorithm.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews any direction on how to sort list based on first argument?

Comment: In addition to the other comments, keep in mind that even if you have to stick with linear search for whatever reason, linear search in a contiguous array (like `vector`) will be way, way faster than linear search in a linked list.

Comment: @Gman: Look up `std::sort`.  You will need to either implement `operator<` or write your own comparison function (or function object).

Comment: Gman is there a reason for not accepting the answer? :/

Answer (score 0):

Searching in a simply linked list is O(n), where `n` is the size of the list.

However, in some implementations, people use three list pointers, one at the start, one at the middle and one at the end, so that when searching comes up - they can speedup the process, so you can search online for this.

BUT, if I were you and was so interesting in speeding up the search, I would try another data structure (hash? like `std::unordered_map`) or sort the list.